# How could I put new block on top of the another block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've had a block 'jumbotron' it has next css parameters:

```css
.jumbotron {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

It's looks so good in the centre of window. But now I want put "container button-block"on that. With next css parameters it looks great too..

```css
.button-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 36%;

}
```

But if I try to change windows size my 'button-block' is starting to dance and brakes design. How can I stick these buttons to jumbotron block What decision will more common?

```css
.jumbotron {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.button-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 36%;

}
```

```html
<div class="page-header"  style="background-image: url('../assets/img/background_presentation.jpg');">
    <div class="container button-block">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl active">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl">2</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl">3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="jumbotron">

            <h2 class="text-center text-white header">What is the property Address</h2>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputAddress" class="text-white">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress">
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputCity" class="text-white">City</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputZip" class="text-white">Zip</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center block-buttons">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-neutral btn-lg">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve? I don't understand the problem. You want those 3 buttons to be sticked to that `jumbotron`?

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @stx yes, ur right

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```css
.container{text-align: center;}
.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
      margin-top: 25%;
  /*transform: translate(-50%,-50%);*/
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.button-block {
  position: absolute;
  top: -22px;
  left: 36%;

}
```

```html
<div class="page-header"  style="background-image: url('../assets/img/background_presentation.jpg');">

    <div class="container">
        <header class="jumbotron">
          <div class="container button-block">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl active">1</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl">2</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-xl">3</button>
          </div>
            <h2 class="text-center text-white header">What is the property Address</h2>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputAddress" class="text-white">Address</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress">
                </div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputCity" class="text-white">City</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="inputZip" class="text-white">Zip</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center block-buttons">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-neutral btn-lg">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But the .jumbotron is not centered any more

Comment: Nope, the window is hides in the bottom. But buttons are sticked really. Like a in snippet

Comment: you talk about centering on vertical?

Comment: @sTx oh I did it! I've removed 'button-block' at all. Thank u so much!